# pygame not found

Tags: python, ubuntu, pygame, python-idle

I am running in ubuntu and I can code in python, without problem. I have tried to install pygame and to do make it so, I did:

> sudo apt-get instal python-pygame

When I go into the python IDLE and write:

> import pygame

I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> ImportError: No module named pygame

What can I do to solve this problem? I am forgetting something, or doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you write `sudo apt-get instal python-pygame` or `sudo apt-get *install* python-pygame`

Comment: Which version of python comes up when you type `$ python`? The (selected) output from `dpkg -l "*python*" | grep "^ii"` would be helpful, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apt-get will install pygame for the registered and pygame-package-supported Python versions. Execute

```
ls -1 /usr/lib/python*/site-packages/pygame/__init__.pyc
```

to find out which. On my old debian system, that prints

```
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pygame/__init__.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/pygame/__init__.pyc
```

That means if I'm not using either Python 2.4 or Python 2.5, pygame will not be available. The Python version your IDLE is using should be displayed at the top (you can also see it with `import sys; print(sys.version)`).

You can either manually install pygame or try to add the installed version with

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/')
import pygame
```

Depending on the complexity of the loaded module(pygame in your case), this might cause some problems later though.

Comment: This work, yes! Is there a way to fix this so I don't need to write:

> sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/')

Comment: @petermlm
As I said, you could try installing it yourself (and should do so if you plan to deliver it to other people). If it's just the typing that bothers you, you can also start a command line terminal, go to the directory you're executing idle in (import os; print(os.getcwd())) and create a symlink with  ln -s /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/pygame.
Btw, if my answer solves your question, consider marking it as accepted so other people know they'll find an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like to download an unpack then install manually, you can use apt to install  **setuptools** . After that you can use **easy_install**(or **easy_install-2.7**?) to install many python packages, including pygame, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same problem!

I read this and while it works to do the sys.path.append thing, I decided to try and get it to work with out.

What I did was went to the Ubuntu Software center uninstalled the python IDLE i had installed and then installed the IDLE.

This seems confusing the way I said it so to clarify you want to download the IDLE that doesn't come with its own version of python, it'll then use the python that already comes with Ubuntu!

If this doesn't make since or doesn't help fix your problem let me know!

Answer (score 0):

check that you are installing pygame for the right version of python. I think the pygame for python 2.7 won't work on python 3.3. I had the same problem but even after installing the right version it didn't work. So after a little googling I found that I was installing pygame meant for 32-bit but my os is 64-bit. so try to google "pygame for window 64-bit" or something like that. I hope it helps.